# librsvg - How to build for android

Tags: android, svg, renderer, librsvg

Anybody have instructions on how to build [libsrvg](https://github.com/GNOME/librsvg) for android (including setting which c++ standard library should be linked to)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you need librsvg in particular? There are already other existing libraries available for rendering SVG on Android.

Comment: https://github.com/pltxtra/libsvgandroid for example. You really need an Android port of the library.